# Why is revolution both "back to" and "away from" a state?

Tags: word-meaning

According to [the internet](https://www.google.se/search?q=meaning+of+revolution&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=ziG5WonmBuuA8QeV5K6QCA) *revolution* is an act of overthrowing the currently effective rule. The word itself, implies that the *circle is completed*, which is rather *returning back to the initial state* than *initializing a new state*.

I've been informed that the current meaning of *revolution* (i.e. *out with old, in with new*) originates in the French revolution of 1789.

While I can accept the above, I'm curious why the concurrent philosophers chose such an, in retrospective, misleading and poorly corresponding nomenclature.

Comment: I'm not going to submit an answer, because I couldn't find any solid answers. But my guess would be that the term probably was used initially to refer to some sense of a "restoration of divine order", because the first revolutions were against absolute monarchs whose excesses were seen as destabilizing of this order, replacing these despots with "just" kings, rather than like modern revolutions based on creating some new form of political system. So the "return back to the initial state" would be seen as restoring a monarchy to some form of just rule. But again, that's only a guess on my part.

Comment: Don't let the guys handing out anarchist pamphlets at the student union get started on this one.

Comment: @J.Taylor I see where you come from but I'm not entirely convinced. As far I understand, the first period when *revolution*'s been used in the modern sense was due to the French dito and that thingy introduced the concept of equal right (men, white etc. but still), democratic idea and elective rulers (as opposed to the power transfer by birth of by Godly will). I'm not claiming that you're mistaken as you definitely make a compelling argument but I'd love to see a rigid reference to a source. Regrettable that you haven't found one.

Comment: The etymology in the full (subscription-only) OED for the relevant "root" word **revolt** says *Middle French revolte (French révolte ) act of uprising against established authority (1501), apostasy (1564) < révolter revolt v. Compare Catalan revolta act of turning back, act of uprising (both 15th cent.), Spanish revuelta (14th cent. or earlier), Portuguese revolta (13th cent. as reuolta ), Italian rivolta act of turning again or back (1374), act of uprising (1540).* I don't see any special reason to extrapolate the sense of turning (180°? 360°?) in a ***circle*** for this usage.

Comment: Makes total sense to me. "The more things change, the more they stay the same." Or, as The Who once famously sang: *Meet the new boss / Same as the old boss.*

Comment: Actually, @Fumble, political revolution *can* easily enough be seen as "doing a 180".  Start with an aristocracy oppressing a peasantry, and then consider the peasantry oppressing the aristocracy.  There's a shift or an inversion there -- those on the top falling to the bottom, those on the bottom rising to the top.  And 'round and 'round she goes, with each new revolution, the bottom overturning the top.

Comment: @Gary: Sure - in the sense of "inverting" society so those who were at the bottom move to the top, and vice-versa. But OP is thinking in terms of "circular, repeating motion" which is all very well in the context of The Who's *Won't Get Fooled Again* (Meet the new boss, same as the old boss), but not really relevant to the "etymology" of the usage as being discussed here.

Comment: Ok.  Granted.  The 180 reference was intended for you.  For OP I might comment that even a one degree shift counts as a revolution.  That word by itself doesn't mean the same as a *complete* revolution.

Comment: I thought revolution came from the Latin _"revolvere"_---to roll back---not to complete a "circle".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan While you're correct scientifically speaking (and mathematically speaking there need not be any rotation at all - posing a revolution of zero degrees), I'm sure the *revolution* of 1789 (and 1917 a bit further to the East) didn't refer to such. Good point, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/revolution), The meaning of "a great change" dates from the 15th century, only 100 years after its earliest use referring to the motion of a planet around the sky.

The political sense was first applied to the overthrow of James II and his replacement with Mary and her Husband William III, now called the "Golden Revolution" (it was done without major bloodshed)

It is reasonable to suppose that the link from the meaning "orbit of a planet" to "great change in affairs" is astrological. The supposition is that when a planet completes an orbit, there will be a great change.

Comment: I think the term can be traced to Fortune's Wheel. We have Lydgate in 1425 using the term to mean **reversal** or **overturning** of the status quo:   *Fortune..Þoruȝ her envious disposicioun Of sodeyn chaunge and reuolucioun..wil nat bide whan a þing is wele.*  Per the MED.

Comment: A good find, and the wheel of fortune is linked to the the zodiac